# Largest palindrome product JAVA

Tags: java, palindrome

i've written code for problem 4 @ https://projecteuler.net/problem=4

**Here is the question :**

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
>   made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
>   numbers.

**Here is my code**

I've tested it and for the 1st loop it iterates 2 times (for i=100 and 101) and for the 2nd loop it iterates to 991 (j=991)

Can you look into my code and help me to find where is the problem ?

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {   



        int resultMult =0;
        String strResultMult = "";
        String even1stHalf = ""; 
        String even2ndHalf = ""; 
        String maxPalindromEven = ""; 
        String odd1stHalf = ""; 
        String odd2ndHalf = ""; 
        String maxPalindromOdd = "";


        for (int i=100;i<=999;i++) 
        {   
            for(int j=100;j<=999;j++) 
            {   
                resultMult = i*j;
                strResultMult = String.valueOf(resultMult);
                if(strResultMult.length()%2==0) 
                {
                    for (int k=0;k<strResultMult.length()/2 ;i++)
                    {
                        even1stHalf = even1stHalf + strResultMult.charAt(k);
                    }
                    for (int l=strResultMult.length()-1;l>=strResultMult.length()/2;l--)
                    {
                        even2ndHalf = even2ndHalf + strResultMult.charAt(l);
                    }
                    if(even1stHalf.equals(even2ndHalf))
                    {
                        maxPalindromEven = strResultMult;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int m=0;m<strResultMult.length()/2 ;m++)
                    {
                        odd1stHalf = odd1stHalf + strResultMult.charAt(m);
                    }
                    for (int n=strResultMult.length()-1;n>strResultMult.length()/2 ;n--)
                    {
                        odd2ndHalf = odd2ndHalf + strResultMult.charAt(n);
                    }
                    if(odd1stHalf.equals(odd2ndHalf))
                    {
                        maxPalindromOdd = strResultMult;
                    }

                }
        }           
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Personally, I'm not willing to be your code reviewer.

Comment: Decompose your code: implement a method `boolean isPalindrome(String value)`

Comment: Ty Dmitry, going to save it in my mind

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
for (int k=0;k<strResultMult.length()/2 ;i++)
                                         ^
```

I believe you meant to write :

```
for (int k=0;k<strResultMult.length()/2 ;k++)
                                         ^
```

Comment: I found it 2 min ago, ty sir :)

Still working on other problems

Comment: @Przemek85 Good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Code *decomposition* made the problem *easier* to debug:

```
  private static boolean isPalindrome(String value) {
    if (null == value)
      return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length() / 2; ++i)
      if (value.charAt(i) != value.charAt(value.length() - 1 - i))
        return false;

    return true;
  }

  ...

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; ++i)
      for (int j = i; j <= 999; ++j) { // i*j == j*i so you can start from i
        int product = i * j;

        if ((product > max) && isPalindrome(String.valueOf(product)))
          max = product;
      }
    ...
```

Comment: Ty, going to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.It displays the largest 3-digit palindrome number:-

```
class Pal{
boolean pal(int no){
    int d=no,rev=0;
    while(d>0){
        rev=(rev*10)+(d%10);
        d/=10;
    }
    boolean bo=(rev==no)?true:false;
    return bo;
}
void show(){
    int max=0,num=0,mock=0;
    for(int i=100;i<1000;i++){
        for(int j=100;j<1000;j++){
             num=(i*j);
            mock=num;
            if(pal(mock)==true)
            max=num;
        }
    }
System.out.println("Largest Palindrome:-"+max);
}
}
```

Comment: Ty, going to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

Going to test your solutions, but meanwhile still working on my code, seems to be broken at if loop when I try to compare two strings

```
if(even1stHalf.equals(even2ndHalf))
{   
    maxPalindromEven = even1stHalf+even2ndHalf;
    //System.out.println(even1stHalf+even2ndHalf);
}
```

and

```
if(odd1stHalf.equals(odd2ndHalf))
{   
    maxPalindromOdd = odd1stHalf+odd2ndHalf;
    //System.out.println(odd1stHalf+odd2ndHalf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apart from your programming problem, I would comment on your algorithm. Basically you will multiply all possibilities of two numbers `(100=<number< 1000)` and check each product, if it is palindrome, also compare with pre-stored max-palindrome. I don't think this is an efficient way to solve the problem.

How about we think in opposite direction, from the largest palindrome (999999), check **each palindrome**, till find the one which could be multiplied by two numbers in range `[100,1000)`?

so basically, an outter loop:

```
loop n in 999 -100
    build string n = n + reverse(n)  // here we have palindrome
    //check if there are two factors of n, 
    //which fall in range [100,999] 
    sqrtRoot = sqrt(n)
    if sqrtRoot is integer, we found the factor, n is the number
    else
        a=b=sqrtRoot
        while(a<1000 and b > 99)
                if a*b==n
                    factors = [a,b]
                    break
                else if a*b >n
                    b--
                else // here is the a*b<n case
                    a++
    //here we have the factors, found or not found. 
    // if we found factor, n is the largest number
```